# Can you conditionally remove a function parameter based on a template parameter?

Tags: c++, function-templates

my function looks like this

```
template<bool extra>
void func(int& arg1, const int arg2){
    //a lot of code...
    if (extra && arg2 > 0) ++arg1;
    arg1 *= 10;
    //a lot of code...
}
```

the problem is that when `extra` is `false`, `arg2` is not used, but the function still requires it to be specified leading to unnecessary memory allocation for `arg2` (you can check assembly output [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:12,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:23,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:23,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:23,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:23,startLineNumber:6),source:%27template%3Cbool+extra%3E%0Avoid+func(int%26+arg1,+const+int+arg2)%7B%0A++++//a+lot+of+code...%0A++++if+(extra+%26%26+arg2+%3E+0)+%2B%2Barg1%3B%0A++++arg1+*%3D+10%3B%0A++++//a+lot+of+code...%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++int+var%7B1%7D%3B%0A++++func%3Cfalse%3E(var,+0)%3B%0A++++func%3Ctrue%3E(var,+0)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:42.45430809399478,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%270%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:57.545691906005224,l:%274%27,m:100.00000000000001,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)). Is there any way to modify the function so that when `extra` is `false`, it only takes `arg1`, avoiding memory allocation for `arg2` in that case?

Comment: A [specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Comment: You just described template specialization. This is an advanced topic that cannot be fully described in one or two sentences on Stackoverflow. See your C++ textbook for a complete description of what it is, how it works, and how to use it.

Comment: Just 2 functions? `func(int& arg1);` `func_extra(int arg1, int arg2)`?

Comment: As usual `// a lot of code...` can still be placed in a function to avoid copy-paste.

Comment: Thare a lot of way to solve the problem but given that your code is abstract (we have no idea what it does), we cannot really tell the best solution in that case. As written, one could simpy use a default value of 0 for arg2: `void func(int &arg1, const int arg2);`.  If that is not enough, then next solution  is 2 functions as suggested by Jarod42.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of problem is commonly solved using [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization),
which [unfortunately](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) typically requires a wrapper struct instead of the plain functions.

Here's an example how that could work:

```cpp
template<bool extra> // default case, only used for extra == false
struct Foo
{
    static void run(int arg1) {
        static_assert(extra == false);
        //...
    }
};
 
template<> //specialization, used for extra == true
struct Foo<true> 
{
    static void run(int arg1, const int arg2) {
        //...
    }
};

int main(){
    Foo<false>::run(1);
    Foo<true>::run(2, 3);
}
```

Depending on the desired API, you can sometimes create a wrapper function or use `operator()` to avoid the slightly ugly `::run` calls.

---

In your specific example, where the signature of the two function version differs (because you don't expect `arg2` for the `extra == true` case), you could even get away with basic [function overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution):

```cpp
// In this simple case you could even remove the template argument completely 
// and make the distinction purely based on the number of arguments.
// It all depends on what API you want to provide.
template<bool extra>
void func(int& arg1){
    static_assert(extra == false);
}
template<bool extra>
void func(int& arg1, const int arg2){
    static_assert(extra == true);
}
```

Note: If the template parameter should stay, a [C++ 20 `requires` clause](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires) or  [`enable_if` guards](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) instead of the `static_assert`s would express the intent of the function signature more accurately, currently at the cost of [arguably worse error messages](https://godbolt.org/z/6Pjbz4s9Y).

Comment: struct template specialization looks pretty ugly in this situation honestly, but function overloading is a perfect solution, i don't know why i didn't came up with it myself, thank you for such a detailed answer!

Comment: It would probably be cleaner if you used a requires-clause instead of static_assert.

Comment: or SFINAE if your toolchain isn't new enough to have `requires`

Comment: @JanSchultke, @BenVoigt:
Here are the comparative error messages for all three cases: https://godbolt.org/z/6Pjbz4s9Y
Even without providing an explicit message for the `static_assert`s, they are already the most readable option in my opinion. Overload resolution always leads to messy errors. KISS. I get that it feels nicer to have a function signature without invalid states, but in practice there is very little difference between `requires` and a `static_assert` in line 1 (unless we have to prevent ambiguous overloads).  Therefore compatability + readability decides for me.

Comment: `requires` is more correct from a theoretical standpoint because it documents intent more clearly and brings the error at the call site, potentially even at lint time with clangd instead of at compile time. The question isn't tagged with [c++17] or lower so C++20 should be assumed. While `requires` is conceptually superior, the diagnostics quality is low and this is unfortunately an area which still needs a fair amount of work from compiler devs. If you don't use an IDE with a decent linter and rely heavily on compiler CLI output, then `static_assert` is much better.

Comment: @JanSchultke: All three error messages include references to both the call site and the called function. But I agree with you on a theoretical / semantical level, so I added a note :).

Comment: Template specialization is permitted for function templates. But only full specializations.

Comment: @BrianBi: You are technically correct. Good catch, edited.